# Ember init failing to recognize _super

Tags: ember.js, components

So my app has this component.js:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import layout from './template';
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    layout = layout;

    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
    }
}
```

When the component is rendered I am getting this error in the chrome console:

`` Assertion Failed: You must call `this._super(...arguments);` when overriding `init` on a framework object. Please update <savings-toolkit@component:my-component::ember2445> to call `this._super(...arguments);` from `init`. ``

The content is not loaded. I wish I could say more, but seriously, what the heck?

Yes, it was initially more much content when I started. It is, however, at this time, literally nothing more than the above.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No one's answering, but I found the answer.

If you are using classes, ie `export default class myComponent extends Component` as opposed to the old way (`export default Component.extend`) you shouldn't use `this._super`. Instead, you use the `super` keyword:

`super.init(...arguments);`

Comment: Please also mind the difference between `constructor` and `init` in native classes. You could find more information about the differences in this awesome blog post: https://www.pzuraq.com/coming-soon-in-ember-octane-part-1-native-classes/